# Fetching using method POST

Tags: post, service, fetch

I just built a small backend with some services, there is a simple service called login which recieves an email and password and returns a msg saying logged. This service works perfectly, because I already test it with post man. The problem is now, that from my frontend im fetching that endpoint and I'm recieving a 400 error.

This is how I'm fetching from my frontend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxUns.png)

And I'm recieving this error...

POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)

These are the Headers..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hEfC.png)

I've checked what I can do, tried many ways to solve, but still recieving the same 400 error.

This is the obj being provided
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Trh.png)

This is my service logic..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtUjw.png)

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more context ? Can you provide the object that is being passed into that function and also the api endpoint logic ?

Comment: @Slaveworx I already edited my questions with the things you were asking for